# ack: Exclude specific directories from search via regex

Tags: regex, ack

How do I ignore specific directories via RegEx with [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)?

I can use the `--ignore-dir` option, but this does not let me specify a RegEx. I want to be able to ignore any directory, which has the words `test` or `tests` or more complicated patterns in its name.

I also tried a negative lookbehind via

```
ack -G '(?<!test)' pattern
```

but this does not work. It does not exclude the `test` directories.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the undocumented option "--invert-file-match" (ack version on my system: 1.96):

```
$ ack pattern -G 'test|tests' --invert-file-match
```

Well, it is sort of documented:

```
$ ack --help|grep invert
-v, --invert-match    Invert match: select non-matching lines
--invert-file-match   Print/search handle files that do not match -g/-G.
```

It is not documented in its perldoc.

Comment: Awesome -- thanks!  Nothing about this in the man page I'm looking at either, but it works.

Answer (score 11):

With ack2, it seems [you can't use holygeek's solution.](http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.0/)

Here's how I'd do it using `-v` and `-x`:

```
ack -v -g 'test' | ack -x pattern
```

More generally, `'test'` can be a regex for dirs to exclude

Comment: Indeed for ack2, this is what you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of ack, you can use regular expressions with `--ignore-dir`.

From [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ack-users/755NSHRWPdQ/PDiJLQgVnUMJ):

> Yes, in 2.15_01 we added:
>
> - ack now supports --ignore-dir=match:....  Thanks, Ailin Nemui! (GitHub ticket #42)

GitHub link: https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/42

Sadly, I think this only supports matching the base directory name, not the full path.

For instance, you cannot match a path like `".*/docs/generated/.*"` with it.

For that, see the [GitHub issue 291](https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/291).

update for 2020: it looks like this is now moved to ack3 ([github issue](https://github.com/beyondgrep/ack3/issues/7)).

Answer (score 5):

In the interest of folks using a pre-1.96 version of ack (like me), you can use regex look around to do this. Here's an example:

```
ack --java 'text-pattern' -G '^((?!(test|target)).)*$'
```

This will search the `text-pattern` in all `Java` files recursively (from .) that DO NOT have the words `test` or `target` in their path.

Comment: What does this construction '^((?!(test|target)).)*$' mean?